# How to solve a really nasty system of nonlinear equations

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to solve a rather nasty system of equations consisting of 160 quadratic equations over 16 variables.  I know there are tons of solutions (tons being at least a subvariety of dimension 6's worth) but the ones I know about aren't the ones I'm interested in.

I tried using fsolve on matlab, but it sometimes fails even when I feed it a solution I know works as a starting point (not all the time though, I suspect its not an error in the equation set, just that it's too many equations for it to handle reliably[mumble mumble... tolerance... mumble]).  Also, using the normal solve function is hilariously inadequate: even if I reduce my system to say 20 quadratics, it still takes quite awhile.

Does anyone know of a computer algebra package or function which can handle something of this magnitude?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd also like to note that I have access to big computers, just a woeful lack of direction/experience with this sort of thing.

Comment: Got the guns, don't got the brains XD not sure how to solve, but it might help to specify your nonlinear function and a bit of code that you tried. Perhaps you could try using grid search or some monte carlo technique?

Comment: fsolve is for solving general systems of non-linear equations. It will be relatively inefficient compared to algorithms which exploit knowledge that the system is quadratic. Try looking at polyhedral homotopy methods. Even if you have access to a 10,000 node cluster step #1 should be finding the right algorithm.